# How (or should) I create my own wiki capabilities?

Tags: asp.net, wiki

I have an ASP.NET website and over time it has become more and more of a data repository where I have numerous database tables and the site just ships out this data.

I am realizing that a *wiki* might actually start to be a better model for what my website is turning into. Or at least parts of it as it's really just adding and updating content that I am doing. Here is my dilema:

There are certain parts of the site that do need to be non-wiki and fully customizable, etc. Should I go and build my own wiki capapabilities into my website so I can make it part wiki (embedded when I need it) and the rest regular ASP.NET? If the answer if yes, are there any tips or boiler plate code on how to build and host a wiki?

The alternative is to use existing wiki software. I have tried most of them and my issue is that I need to host it myself on Windows and as mentioned above I want to have complete control and have just a simple wiki page editable inside my site. I have tried using frames, etc. to simulate this, but it all seems kind of hacky.

Any advice on:

A. If you think I should build the wiki part of my site below, is there best practice, boiler plate code on how to do this quickly?

B. If you think I shouldn't go reinvent the wheel, is there any existing Windows-hosted software that I can embed in my site without losing any control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rolling your own is a waste of time unless you have some major change or addition to the functionality of a wiki not otherwise available in existing systems (and even then, it's often a waste of time to start over than to branch an existing setup).

I recommend using something like [ScrewTurn](http://www.screwturn.eu/), which is open-source and ASP.NET, which gives you a fully-functioning wiki with no development, as well as gives you as much control as necessary if you do need to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Rex M. You don't need to start from scratch. Leverage an open source product that is already available and build on it (if you even need too).

The added benefit of that is from a collaborative perspective when you build some interesting functionality into your version of the software and then share that back with the community.

Chances are if you need to build something and find it useful that other folks somewhere have close to the same needs and would welcome your features and enhancements.

That's the beauty of open source.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [dooWikis](http://dooWikis.com).  With this, you can embed wikis into your site like you want to, without redirecting to a third-party service, and restrict who gets to make edits.